# Spring bean mocking and notice that called a method which annotated by @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, mockito, inject

I try to throw a specific exception when a method call via using doThrow. Then i expect to handle it by a method in its superclass which is annotated @ExceptionHandler. 
1. Should i use Spy or Mock object for my controller class(it is a spring bean)
2. Should i use InjectMocks
3. Should i test within spring context because of ExceptionHandler class which is belonged to Spring

Here is my rough view of Controller class:

```
DefaultPageController extends SuperClass
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws CMSItemNotFoundException
    {....}

}
```

And ParentClass of my Controller(it is abstract)

```
public abstract class SuperClass

{...
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidCsrfTokenException.class)
    public String handleInvalidCsrfTokenException(final InvalidCsrfTokenException exception, final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        request.setAttribute("message", exception.getMessage());
        LOG.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return FORWARD_PREFIX + "/404";
    }
...
}
```

Finally my test class:

```
@IntegrationTest
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PageRedirectOnCSRFTest
{
    @Mock
    private Model model;
    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @Mock
    private InvalidCsrfTokenException invalidCsrfTokenException;
    @Mock
    private MissingCsrfTokenException missingCsrfTokenException;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    private DefaultPageController controller;


    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        try
        {
            doThrow(invalidCsrfTokenException).when(controller).get(model, request, response);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    //private final DefaultPageController controller = Mockito.spy(new DefaultPageController());
    //  private final InvalidCsrfTokenException invalidCsrfTokenException = new InvalidCsrfTokenException(
    //          Mockito.mock(CsrfToken.class), "1234");
    // private final MissingCsrfTokenException missingCsrfTokenException = new MissingCsrfTokenException("1234");

    @Test
    public void testIfCalledHandleInvalidCsrfTokenException()
    {
        try
        {
            controller.get(model, request, response);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            // YTODO Auto-generated catch block
            Assert.assertTrue(e instanceof InvalidCsrfTokenException);
            Mockito.verify(controller, Mockito.times(1)).handleInvalidCsrfTokenException(invalidCsrfTokenException, request);
        }

    }
}
```

Thx and brgs

Comment: Why would you test external library(spring in this case)?
If you want to test handleInvalidCsrfTokenException method, just call it directly on your controller in your test

Comment: Thx for your comment. Essentially, i try to test if controller.get method throws an exception which annotated ExceptionHandler, would handleInvalidCsrfTokenException method really call. Hope that is clearer now. I already know this logic that i want to coverage with unittest, works properly. By the way, maybe you think that this type of test is not appropriate for integration test? If so, do some cases like that not need to cover insistly in your opinion?